# access helper file method in more than one view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

In my `ApplicationHelper.rb`

```
def price_count
   my code is here
end
```

i want to access it in more than one view file.

thank you.

Comment: did you try accessing?

Comment: @nithin yes,i tried it

Comment: what was the error when accessed in other view files?

Comment: getting this error => undefined local variable or method `price_count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have set this

```
config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false
```

in /config/application.rb

Change `false` to `true` and you will be able to access your helper method in all views.